# UserDefaults removeObjectForKey not working?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I have set some value in user default in my app at beginning. Then those values may get overridden by the user and i want to delete those settings.

When i try to delete all default a few key-value removed but a few keys are not removed immediately. When i kill app & again back to app it work as deleted. As i expected it should work immediately after its delete key

Here is my code in swift 3.2 for set default value

```
let sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension = UserDefaults(suiteName: "GROUP_IDENTIFIER")
sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.setValue(newValue, forKey: "My_Key")
sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.synchronize()
```

Code for delete all user default value

```
let sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension = UserDefaults(suiteName: "GROUP_IDENTIFIER")
for key in (sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)! {
    sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.removeObject(forKey: key)
}
sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.synchronize()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete all data from `userdefault` then use:

```
let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: bundleIdentifier)
```

And for `set` the data in user default:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("jogendar", forKey: "My_Key")
```

> And in your way, you need to synchronize the data just after remove but don't try `synchronize()` as mention in doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize
>
> > `synchronize()` :- Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.

```
let sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension = UserDefaults(suiteName: "GROUP_IDENTIFIER")
for key in (sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)! {
    sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.removeObject(forKey: key)
    sharedUserDefaultsWithExtension?.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: `.synchronize()` is now obsolete, as explained in the documentation. It should be removed from any code using UserDefaults.

Comment: @Moritz: Thanks, Yes it should be removed